# Put structs in an array

Tags: swift

I would like to put structs in an array. I just can not, I can not imagine that this is impossible.

The code I have so far is:

```
struct PersonA {
     var name: String
     var surname: String
     var phone: Int }

var contactsA: [PersonA] = []

var person1: PersonA = PersonA (name: "Jack", surname: "Johnson", phone: 2)
var person2: PersonA = PersonA (name: "alex", surname: "a", phone: 3)

contactsA.append (person1)
contactsA.append (person2)

for contact in contactsA {
     print ("\ (contact.name) \ (contact.surge)")
}
```

In this code I use the vars person1 and person2. I have to make a lot of contacts so I would like to do this without having to make a separate variable for each contact.

Comment: Your question starts out as if you are not able to put structs in an array. But clearly you have no problem doing that. It seems your question is only asking how to do it without creating separate variables for each.

Comment: Translation: Your question, while very good, isn't something **as worded in both title (and maybe verbiage)** that is anything anybody else can be helped by. I see where you've accepted an answer. Any chance you could help others by editing your question? It isn't normal to see two answers with more than one upvote and yet the question has more than one downvote. (I was the third downvote and will gladly remove it if you edit the question.)

Comment: You should edit your question to say something like "I can't figure out how to add multiple contacts to an array without having to define a variable for each new contact." That would make it clear the problem you are having. As it is your question is kind of confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add a person to contacts without binding it to a variable just do:

```
struct PersonA {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var phone: Int
}

var contactsA: [PersonA] = []

contactsA.append(PersonA(name: "Jack", surname: "Johnson", phone: 2))
contactsA.append(PersonA(name: "alex", surname: "a", phone: 2))

for contact in contactsA {
    print("\(contact.name) \(contact.surname)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need separate variables. You have a few options:

Option 1:

```
var contactsA = [PersonA]()

contactsA.append(PersonA(name: "Jack", surname: "Johnson", phone: 2))
contactsA.append(PersonA(name: "alex", surname: "a", phone: 3))
```

Option 2:

```
var contactsA = [
    PersonA(name: "Jack", surname: "Johnson", phone: 2)),
    PersonA(name: "alex", surname: "a", phone: 3))
]
```